# Como pegar uma data através de um form e inseri-la no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com o seguinte problema: Não estou conseguindo pegar a hora atual e inseri-la no banco.

```html
<div class="container">
   <h2>Registrando ponto</h2>

   <form class="form" method="POST" action="registroHora.php">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"     name="codEntrada">Entrada</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="codSaida">Saída</button>
   </form>
  </div>
```

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

$codEntrada = $_POST['codEntrada'];
$codSaida = $_POST['codSaida'];
$codUser = $_POST['codUser'];


$sql = "insert into registroPonto (codEntrada, codSaida, codUser)
    values('$codEntrada', '$codSaida', '$codUser')";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Ponto Registrado";
    header('location: area-usuario.php');
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Usuário não Cadastrado.";
    header('location: cadastro.php');
}

?>

    create table cadastroUsuario(
    codUser int not null auto_increment primary key,
    userNome varchar(100) not null,
    userEmail varchar(100) not null,
    userSenha varchar(100) not null,
    userConfirmaSenha varchar(100) not null
);

create table registroPonto(
    codPonto int not null auto_increment primary key,
    codEntrada datetime not null,
    codSaida datetime not null,
    codUser int not null,
    constraint fk_ponto_usuario FOREIGN KEY (codUser)
    REFERENCES cadastroUsuario (codUser)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar direto na sua pagina registroHora.php usando

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

ou coloca no HTML em um input

```
<input type="date" name="datahora" value="<?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>" />
```

> ou direto no comando de insert do SQL, no caso, no MySql voce pode
>   usar o 'NOW()'